# Environment variable in user-data script

Tags: vagrant, environment-variables, user-data, cloud-init

I am having a problem with getting my user-data script to read an environment variable that gets set before the execution of the script. I am testing this using Vagrant.

So I have this line in my Vagrantfile...

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bin/vagrant/build.sh"
```

... that points to the provisioning script. The script contains everything necessary to load cloud-init, as outlined [here](http://davemartorana.com/logs/software/cloud-init-in-vagrant-with-ubuntu-12-10-13-04/).

Inside `build.sh`, I have a line...

```
echo "SOME_PATH=/some/path" >> /etc/environment
```

... which presumably makes the environment variable available globally.

The full file, if you are interested:

```
echo "SOME_PATH=/some/path" >> /etc/environment

# Check to see if we have done this already.
if [ -f /.vagrant_build_done ]; then
    echo "Found, not running."
    exit
fi

# Make the box think it hasn't init-ed yet.
rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/instance/*
rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data

# Seed our own init scripts
cat << 'END_OF_FILE_CONTENTS' > /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============apiserversStackMultipartMessage=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

# Beginning of our user-data script.
--===============apiserversStackMultipartMessage==

#include
/vagrant/bin/vagrant/user-data.sh

--===============apiserversStackMultipartMessage==--
END_OF_FILE_CONTENTS
# End of our user-data script.

# Re-run cloud-init.
cloud-init init
cloud-init modules --mode init
cloud-init modules --mode config
cloud-init modules --mode final

# Do not let this run again.
touch /.vagrant_build_done
```

Now, I have a line that echoes `SOME_PATH` inside `/vagrant/bin/vagrant/user-data.sh` like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $SOME_PATH
```

... and when I run `vagrant up`, nothing gets printed!

Is there a way to make the environment variable available inside `user-data.sh`?

Answer (score 3):

the variable has been added to `/etc/environment` so you should be able to see the value when you ssh into the box but at the time of the script its not yet available, you need to create a new session for this.

you can do one of the following, on top of what you're currently doing:

1. directly export the variable `SOME_PATH` in the script so its available when you execute `user-data.sh`
2. `source /etc/environment` (after you added the variable) so the changes made in the file will take effect directly.